# wicked_pdf (with wkhtmltopdf) not rendering correctly

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, pdf

I need to convert an existing html document to pdf. I use [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) for this task. But there are a lot of things which don’t render correctly:

1. hyphenation
2. rounded border on images
3. other stuff which I don’t care about that much at the moment

#### Hyphenation

When the pdf is created all paragraphs with hyphenation enabled are rendered without it. The CSS looks like this:

```
p {
  margin-top            : 0;

  -webkit-hyphens       : auto;
  -moz-hyphens          : auto;
  -ms-hyphens           : auto;
  -o-hyphens            : auto;
  hyphens               : auto;

  hyphenate-limit-chars : auto 5;
  hyphenate-limit-lines : 2;

  widows: 3;
  orphans: 3;
}
```

#### Rounded borders and images

I’ve got a container with rounded corners. Inside at the top of this container is an image displayed which should have rounded corners too. Unfortunately the image is rendered without rounded corners. It overlaps the container border which look pretty ugly.

The HAML for this container:

```
.profile-picture-container
  = cl_image_tag @presenter.profile_picture, class: 'profile-picture'
  .profile-picture-body
    %p
      = @presenter.user_fullname
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
.profile-picture-container {
  float                      : right;
  margin-left                : 5mm;
  margin-right               : -15mm;
  border                     : 1px solid lightgray;
  border-bottom-left-radius  : 0.25rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius : 0.25rem;
  overflow                   : hidden;
}
.profile-picture-container, .profile-picture {
  width : 50mm;
}
.profile-picture {
  // -1px stolen from bootstrap’s definitions
  border-top-left-radius  : calc(0.25rem - 1px);
  border-top-right-radius : calc(0.25rem - 1px);
}
.profile-picture-body {
  padding : 3mm 5mm;
}
```

#### Other stuff not working correctly

Headings ignore their `page-break-after: avoid;` setting.

Is it just me or is html to pdf conversion not ready for primetime?